# Defining relations between variables.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic

Generally we define relations between a variable $x$ and $y$ $y=f(x)$ and this will hold for all values that we allow that variable to take, and we say that $y$ depend on $x$, my question is simply, can we define relations that are only true for a *certain combination* of values of $x$ and $y$, so, given two otherwise independent variables we can define something like:

For a certain combination of values of $x$,$y$

$x=y$

and hence

$f(x)=f(y)$

Is this acceptable, of course in this instance $x$ and $y$ do not depend on each other, would this be equivalent to something like:

$∃x∃y(x=y)$

Again, these are not dependent on each other over $R$ just that if we substitute the same value into $x$ and $y$ the following relation will be true, but $x$ and $y$ can still be anything. So we could have a formula relating two otherwise unrelated quantities and can express when they may happen to have the same value.

Comment: A relation is somethng expressed by $R(x,y)$ that hold for some values of x and y, è. g. $(x < y)$

Comment: so defining any relation is fine as long as I understand the context? So for formulas we would take the particular understanding that this is true for many particular combinations of values in a range of validity.

Comment: To obtain, $f(x)=f(y)$, it is necessary have both $x$ and $y$ in the domain of $f$. It is not sufficient to say that $x=y$.

Comment: Of course, that would be part of the 'range of validity' for the statements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by dependent and independent variables in this context, but if $x=y$ and $x$ is a an element of the domain of $f$, then, whatever else may be true, we can infer that $f(x)=f(y).$

Comment: $x$ and $y$ are free to vary, e.g having $x=4$ doesn't imply that $y=4$, but it may still be true.

Comment: If $x$ is in the domain of function $f$, then we can obtain $f(x)=f(x)$. Substituting $x=y$ on the RHS, we can obtain $f(x)=f(y)$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: pretty much, so its therefore to define, for certain $x$ and $y$ values this will be true, but not for all, e.g. I can show something like for linear functions if $x=ay$ then $f(x) = af(y)$